# Copy json, but update only keys that exists in target

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I have two JSON objects, `original` and `current`.

The `original` object was created by reading a configuration file, it have a certain specific keys.

The `current` object was created as a copy of `original`, then there are keys added to `current`, as well as updates to other keys from `original`.

Now I want to copy back from `current` to `original`, but *only* the keys that exists in `original`. In other words, I don't want the new keys that was added to `current`.

For example, lets say `original` is:

```
{
    "foo": "hello"
}
```

And `current` is:

```
{
    "foo": "world",
    "bar": "some other stuff"
}
```

After updating `original` only the `"foo"` key should have been updated:

```
{
    "foo": "world"
}
```

The `"bar"` key is not copied.

Using the nlohmann-json library, is there a simple way to solve this? Or do I have to iterate over `original` and explicitly copy those keys from `current`?

Comment: Stupid idea: use `json::diff` to make a JSON Patch, remove all members with `type != "replace"`, apply patch with `json::patch`.

Comment: @Botje Maybe a *little* stupid... ;) But still a valid suggestion to think about.